# g77 cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: linux, gcc, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to compile a model which is written in FORTRAN 77. I am not able to make the link for g77.

**My system details:**
Ubuntu 14.04 as a Virtual machine in Windows 8.

I am getting the below error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

I checked for `libgcc_s` location and I got

```
/home/am14f01/Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/home/am14f01/Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1

/home/am14f01/Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
/home/am14f01/Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1

/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Now I don't know exactly how to link. Kindly help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: You may need to put gcc 3.4 on PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH if that matches g77 but why not use gfortran with gcc 4.8?

Comment: How did you install g77? This is likely the issue here and I second tim18's suggestion to use the Ubuntu provided compiler.